# Подключение openssl в проект visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, библиотеки, openssl, md5

библиотека openssl. Необходимо использовать метод MD5.
Подрубаю библиотеку:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"libcrypto.lib")
#include<openssl/MD5.h>
```

юзаю код

```
md = MD5(value->dsc_address, value->dsc_length, digest);
```

Но выходит ошибка:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ MD5 в функции
>   "struct dsc * __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::evlGenUuid(class
>   Jrd::thread_db *,class SysFunction const *,class Firebird::Array,class Firebird::EmptyStorage > > const &,struct
>   Jrd::impure_value *)"
>   (?evlGenUuid@?A0x2bb19745@@YAPEAUdsc@@PEAVthread_db@Jrd@@PEBVSysFunction@@AEBV?$Array@V?$NestConst@VValueExprNode@Jrd@@@@V?$EmptyStorage@V?$NestConst@VValueExprNode@Jrd@@@@@Firebird@@@Firebird@@PEAUimpure_value@4@@Z)  engine1

Подскажите что не так, либы пробовал по всякому, даже так:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"capi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dasync.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libapps.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libcrypto.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libcrypto_static.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libssl.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libssl_static.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"libtestutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"openssl.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"ossltest.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"padlock.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"uitest.lib")
```

Естественно в свойствах проекта прописал пути к Includes и Libries

Comment: Проверьте архитектура вашего приложения и библиотеки(x32 или x64), а также тип сборки(Debug или Release), по хорошему они должны совпадать... Скорее всего ошибка в этом.